# Does animal growth enlarge barding worn by the target?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, armor, animals

If Animal Growth is cast on an armored animal companion (i.e., going from large to huge size) what happens to the original large armor? Does it also grow with the creature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Animal Growth**](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/animal-growth/)

> All equipment worn or carried by the animal is similarly enlarged by the spell, though this change has no effect on the magical properties of any such equipment.
>
> Any enlarged item that leaves the enlarged creature’s possession instantly returns to its normal size.

Answer (score 4):

### Yes

From [Animal Growth](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/animal-growth/):

> All equipment worn or carried by the animal is similarly enlarged by the spell, though this change has no effect on the magical properties of any such equipment.